# So I am currently trying to upload an app to PlayStore but I need to upgrade my react native project from api lvl 28 to 29

Tags: android, react-native

So I am trying to upgrade my react native project from API level 28 to 29 and I have android studio but there are a lot of build.gradle folders under different expo folders. Can anyone tell me if I have to change every folder to 29 or a specific one? And by the way, how do I sync gradle in android studio? I don't know the version but I got it on April 25th, 2021. My project is using SDK 37.0.0 because certain features don't work in other SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps :-

- Open `android/build.gradle` in your React Native project.
- Then increment the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` values to `29`.

> In `android/build.gradle`

```
   buildscript {
       ext {
           buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
           minSdkVersion = 16
           compileSdkVersion = 29
           targetSdkVersion = 29
       }
       // ...
   }

   allprojects {
    // ...
   }
```

- Then in Android Studio, Run "Sync Project with Gradle Files" (`File` > `Sync Project with Gradle Files`).

And you should be all set.

Comment: But I have multiple build.gradle files for example: 
node_modules/react-native/template/android/build.gradle
node_modules/expo-constants/android/build.gradle
node_modules/expo-file-system/android/build.gradle

And when I click on files the sync project with gradle files isn't there.

Comment: Ok I found that sync project with gradle files is disabled, how do I enable it?

Comment: @AnikDey Try this -
Go to File > Invalidate cache / restart .